# Which tool is good for Defect tracking/Logging in testing for testers?

Tags: testing

Any one can give the information about which tools are free for Defect Tracking/Logging and For Reporting the Bugs on the net. I have searched there is no free tools are available for defect tracking on the net. I have find out some tools Bontq, FogBugz, Mantis, Dev Track and Bugzilla. but these all are paid up tools only. I have registered for free trail version, In that I felt Bontq is good for adding Bugs, adding cases and then email notifications and for reporting the information to developers. 
Can any body please suggest me, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/)

Open source projects are free on Assembla. But that might not be your case.

[Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/) is free by the way.

[FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) is free in the following case:

> The FogBugz Student and Startup
>   Edition allows teams of one or two
>   people to use a complete,
>   full-featured version of FogBugz,
>   professionally hosted at our data
>   center, at absolutely no cost

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, I am inviting you on the "Tester's Talk" room for chating or reviewing the queries and answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many topics on that matter. I suggest you [look through them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[bug-tracking]+free).

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, I am inviting you on the "Tester's Talk" room for chating or reviewing the queries and answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Mantis][1] is free and easily customisable

[1]: http://www.mantisbt.org/ Mantis

Comment: Kirkham, thanks for your suggestions, I am inviting you on the "Tester's Talk" room for chating or reviewing the queries and answers. Thank you.